# TensorFlow: "NotImplementedError: When subclassing the `Model` class, you should implement a `call` method."

Tags: tensorflow2.x

inside "PWCDCNet.py" I have defined the following ANN:

```
class Conv2D(tfk.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, strides, name=None, padding=1, dilation_rate=1):
    super(Conv2D, self).__init__(name=name)
    
    self.conv_out = tfk.layers.Conv2D(filters=filters,
                                  kernel_size=kernel_size, 
                                  strides=strides, 
                                  padding='same',
                                  kernel_initializer='he_normal',
                                  dilation_rate=dilation_rate,
                                  activation=tfk.layers.LeakyReLU(0.1))

    def call(self, inputs):
        return self.conv_out(inputs)

class DeConv2D(tfk.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size=4, strides=2, name=None):
        super(DeConv2D, self).__init__(name=name)
    
    self.deconv_out = tfk.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=filters,
                                            kernel_size=kernel_size, 
                                            strides=strides, 
                                            padding='same',
                                            name=name)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return self.deconv_out(inputs)


def CostVolumn(c1, warp, search_range, name='cost_volumn'):

    padded_lvl = tf.pad(warp, [[0, 0], [search_range, search_range], [search_range, search_range], [0, 0]])
    _, h, w, _ = tf.unstack(tf.shape(c1))
    max_offset = search_range * 2 + 1

    cost_vol = []
    for y in range(0, max_offset):
        for x in range(0, max_offset):
            slice = tf.slice(padded_lvl, [0, y, x, 0], [-1, h, w, -1])
            cost = tf.reduce_mean(c1 * slice, axis=3, keepdims=True)
            cost_vol.append(cost)
    cost_vol = tf.concat(cost_vol, axis=3)
    cost_vol = tf.nn.leaky_relu(cost_vol, alpha=0.1, name=name)

    return cost_vol

class PredictFlow(tfk.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        super(PredictFlow, self).__init__()

        self.conv_out = tfk.layers.Conv2D(filters=2,
                                  kernel_size=3, 
                                  strides=1,
                                  name=name,
                                  padding='same')

    def call(self, inputs):
        return self.conv_out(inputs)

class PWCDCNet(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, max_displacement=4):
        super(PWCDCNet, self).__init__()

        self.conv1a  = Conv2D( 16, kernel_size=3, strides=2, name='conv1a')
        self.conv1aa = Conv2D( 16, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv1aa')
        self.conv1b  = Conv2D( 16, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv1b')
        self.conv2a  = Conv2D( 32, kernel_size=3, strides=2, name='conv2a')
        self.conv2aa = Conv2D( 32, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv2aa')
        self.conv2b  = Conv2D( 32, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv2b')
        self.conv3a  = Conv2D( 64, kernel_size=3, strides=2, name='conv3a')
        self.conv3aa = Conv2D( 64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv3aa')
        self.conv3b  = Conv2D( 64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv3b')
        self.conv4a  = Conv2D( 96, kernel_size=3, strides=2, name='conv4a')
        self.conv4aa = Conv2D( 96, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv4aa')
        self.conv4b  = Conv2D( 96, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv4b')
        self.conv5a  = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=2, name='conv5a')
        self.conv5aa = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv5aa')
        self.conv5b  = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv5b')
        self.conv6aa = Conv2D(196, kernel_size=3, strides=2, name='conv6aa')
        self.conv6a  = Conv2D(196, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv6a')
        self.conv6b  = Conv2D(196, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv6b')

        self.LeakyReLU = tfk.layers.LeakyReLU(0.1, name='LeakyReLU')

        self.conv6_0 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv6_0')
        self.conv6_1 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv6_1')
        self.conv6_2 = Conv2D(96,  kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv6_2')
        self.conv6_3 = Conv2D(64,  kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv6_3')
        self.conv6_4 = Conv2D(32,  kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv6_4')
        self.deconv6 = DeConv2D(2, kernel_size=4, strides=2, name='deconv_6')
        self.upfeat6 = DeConv2D(2, kernel_size=4, strides=2, name='upfeat_6')

        self.conv5_0 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv5_0')
        self.conv5_1 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv5_1')
        self.conv5_2 = Conv2D(96,  kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv5_2')
        self.conv5_3 = Conv2D(64,  kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv5_3')
        self.conv5_4 = Conv2D(32,  kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv5_4')
        self.deconv5 = DeConv2D(2, kernel_size=4, strides=2, name='deconv_5')
        self.upfeat5 = DeConv2D(2, kernel_size=4, strides=2, name='upfeat_5')

        self.conv4_0 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv4_0')
        self.conv4_1 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv4_1')
        self.conv4_2 = Conv2D(96,  kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv4_2')
        self.conv4_3 = Conv2D(64,  kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv4_3')
        self.conv4_4 = Conv2D(32,  kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv4_4')
        self.deconv4 = DeConv2D(2, kernel_size=4, strides=2, name='deconv4')
        self.upfeat4 = DeConv2D(2, kernel_size=4, strides=2, name='upfeat4')

        self.conv3_0 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv3_0')
        self.conv3_1 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv3_1')
        self.conv3_2 = Conv2D(96,  kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv3_2')
        self.conv3_3 = Conv2D(64,  kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv3_3')
        self.conv3_4 = Conv2D(32,  kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv3_4')
        self.deconv3 = DeConv2D(2, kernel_size=4, strides=2, name='deconv3')
        self.upfeat3 = DeConv2D(2, kernel_size=4, strides=2, name='upfeat3')

        self.conv2_0 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv2_0')
        self.conv2_1 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv2_1')
        self.conv2_2 = Conv2D(96,  kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv2_2')
        self.conv2_3 = Conv2D(64,  kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv2_3')
        self.conv2_4 = Conv2D(32,  kernel_size=3, strides=1, name='conv2_4')
        self.deconv2 = DeConv2D(2, kernel_size=4, strides=2, name='deconv2')

        self.dc_conv1 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding=1,  dilation_rate=1, name='dc_conv1')
        self.dc_conv2 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding=2,  dilation_rate=2, name='dc_conv2')
        self.dc_conv3 = Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding=4,  dilation_rate=4, name='dc_conv3')
        self.dc_conv4 = Conv2D(96,  kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding=8,  dilation_rate=8, name='dc_conv4')
        self.dc_conv5 = Conv2D(64,  kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding=16, dilation_rate=16, name='dc_conv5')
        self.dc_conv6 = Conv2D(32,  kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding=1,  dilation_rate=1, name='dc_conv6')

        self.predict_flow6 = PredictFlow(name='predict_flow6')
        self.predict_flow5 = PredictFlow(name='predict_flow5')
        self.predict_flow4 = PredictFlow(name='predict_flow4')
        self.predict_flow3 = PredictFlow(name='predict_flow3')
        self.predict_flow2 = PredictFlow(name='predict_flow2')
        self.dc_conv7 = PredictFlow(name='dc_conv7')

    def call(self, inputs):
        im1 = inputs[:, :, :, :3]
        im2 = inputs[:, :, :, 3:]
        c11 = self.conv1b(self.conv1aa(self.conv1a(im1)))
        c21 = self.conv1b(self.conv1aa(self.conv1a(im2)))
        c12 = self.conv2b(self.conv2aa(self.conv2a(c11)))
        c22 = self.conv2b(self.conv2aa(self.conv2a(c21)))
        c13 = self.conv3b(self.conv3aa(self.conv3a(c12)))
        c23 = self.conv3b(self.conv3aa(self.conv3a(c22)))
        c14 = self.conv4b(self.conv4aa(self.conv4a(c13)))
        c24 = self.conv4b(self.conv4aa(self.conv4a(c23)))
        c15 = self.conv5b(self.conv5aa(self.conv5a(c14)))
        c25 = self.conv5b(self.conv5aa(self.conv5a(c24)))
        c16 = self.conv6b(self.conv6a(self.conv6aa(c15)))
        c26 = self.conv6b(self.conv6a(self.conv6aa(c25)))

        ### 6th flow    
        corr6 = CostVolumn(c1=c16, warp=c26, search_range=4)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv6_0(corr6), corr6], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv6_1(x), x], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv6_2(x), x], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv6_3(x), x], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv6_4(x), x], 3)
    
        flow6 = self.predict_flow6(x)
        up_flow6 = self.deconv6(flow6)
        up_feat6 = self.upfeat6(x)    

        ### 5th flow
        warp5 = bilinear_warp(c25, up_flow6*0.625)
        corr5 = CostVolumn(c1=c15, warp=warp5, search_range=4)

        x = tf.concat([corr5, c15, up_flow6, up_feat6], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv5_0(x), x], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv5_1(x), x], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv5_2(x), x], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv5_3(x), x], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv5_4(x), x], 3)
        flow5 = self.predict_flow5(x)
        up_flow5 = self.deconv5(flow5)
        up_feat5 = self.upfeat5(x)

        ### 4th flow
        warp4 = bilinear_warp(c24, up_flow5*1.25)
        corr4 = CostVolumn(c1=c14, warp=warp4, search_range=4)

        x = tf.concat([corr4, c14, up_flow5, up_feat5], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv4_0(x), x], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv4_1(x), x], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv4_2(x), x], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv4_3(x), x], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv4_4(x), x], 3)
        flow4 = self.predict_flow4(x)
        up_flow4 = self.deconv4(flow4)
        up_feat4 = self.upfeat4(x)

        ### 3rd flow
        warp3 = bilinear_warp(c23, up_flow4*2.5)
        corr3 = CostVolumn(c1=c13, warp=warp3, search_range=4)
    
        x = tf.concat([corr3, c13, up_flow4, up_feat4], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv3_0(x), x], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv3_1(x), x], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv3_2(x), x], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv3_3(x), x], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv3_4(x), x], 3)
        flow3 = self.predict_flow3(x)
        up_flow3 = self.deconv3(flow3)
        up_feat3 = self.upfeat3(x)

        # 2nd flow
        warp2 = bilinear_warp(c22, up_flow3*5.0) 
        corr2 = CostVolumn(c1=c12, warp=warp2, search_range=4)

        x = tf.concat([corr2, c12, up_flow3, up_feat3], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv2_0(x), x], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv2_1(x), x], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv2_2(x), x], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv2_3(x), x], 3)
        x = tf.concat([self.conv2_4(x), x], 3)
        flow2 = self.predict_flow2(x)

        x = self.dc_conv4(self.dc_conv3(self.dc_conv2(self.dc_conv1(x))))
        flow2 = flow2 + self.dc_conv7(self.dc_conv6(self.dc_conv5(x)))

        return flow2
```

This ANN gets imported into another file:

```
from PWCNet_tf2.PWCDCNet import PWCDCNet
PWC_model = tf.keras.Model(PWCDCNet())
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(PWC_model)
save_path = checkpoint.save('/some_directories/PWCNet_tf2/checkpoints/0001/tf_ckpt')
checkpoint.restore(save_path)
```

But if I try to:

```
output =  PWC_model(input)
```

I get the error:

```
NotImplementedError: When subclassing the `Model` class, you should implement a `call` method.
```

I am wondering, as a call method is implemented for every Layer, but also for the ANN as a whole. Is the error due to the way I import the model?

Thanks to all of you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The error was that I called:

```
PWC_model = tf.keras.Model(PWCDCNet())
```

instead of:

```
PWC_model = PWCDCNet()
```